# Python 3 .write() is adding a 0 to the end of .txt file when input is > 10

Tags: python

Thank you in advance for any help and patience !

I am making a very basic game where i have a bank, there is a bank withdraw function that lives in the bank, so the user can withdraw money from a separate file (bank.txt) it works and writes fine with up input above 10 however once the remaining allowance to be updated after a withdrawal is less that 10 it writes an extra 0 to the end of the text file (show in 2nd set of print str

```py
def bank_withdraw(): global wallet

while True:
    input_file_1.seek(0)
    contents = input_file_1.read()

print(f"You have {contents} in your bank, how much would you like to withdraw?")

withdraw = input("> ")

if withdraw.isnumeric():

        withdraw_int = int(withdraw)
        contents_int = int(contents)
        if contents_int - withdraw_int < 0:
            print("Im sorry, you don't have enough funds...")
    
        elif contents_int - withdraw_int >= 0:                
            print("contents of bank.txt", contents_int)      #1st run  15   # 2nd run 10
            print("withdraw amount input", withdraw_int)     # 5           # 5
            new_balance = contents_int - withdraw_int        
            print("new balance after contents - withdraw input", new_balance) # 10  #5
            converted_new_balance = str(new_balance) 
            print('converted new balance str(new_balance)', converted_new_balance) #10 #5
    
            wallet += withdraw_int
            input_file_1.seek(0)
            **input_file_1.write(converted_new_balance)**  #this is where the 0 is added
            input_file_1.seek(0)
            print('input file converted balance print', input_file_1.read())  #10   #50
            print(f"Thank you for withdrawing {withdraw} gold or silver or whatever."
                  f"You have {wallet} in your wallet")
    check_file = "bank.txt"
if os.path.isfile(check_file):
    print(f""""Existing Save File Detected '{check_file}'...
```

```
# This is how the input_file_1 variable is established
```

`Would you like to OPEN or create NEW save file?""")`
`choice = input('>')`

```
if choice.lower() == "open":
    print("Saved Bank Opened")
    input_file_1 = open(check_file, 'r+')
    print(input_file_1.read())`
```

`thank in advance !`

Comment: When you seek to the beginning of the file,  and there were 2 digits there, if you write one digit, then the 2nd digit will remain. A textfile is really not the best approach for this because textfiles are not well adapted to random access. Consider using `pickle`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, when you seek to the beginning of the file, and there were 2 digits there, if you write one digit, then the 2nd digit will remain. A textfile is really not the best approach for this because textfiles are not well adapted to random access. Consider using `pickle`.